# How to commit modified records or update the records in store & commit it to the server?

Tags: sencha-touch

I have record objects in store as i have mentioned below(structure is of a single record in a store):

```
data: Object
dirty: true
events: Object
internalId: "ext-record-14"
modified: Object
needsAdd: false
phantom: false
store: Object
```

Now, we have insert,remove, add methods of store to handle records at store level but I want to update records at store level similar to the updateRecord of FormPanel method.

I want to update all the records which are dirty to the server.

Comment: Isn't [`store.sync`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/#/api/Ext.data.Store-method-sync) that what you want?

Comment: I want store.sync only but its not working for me. Steps I followed are: 1) var records = store.data.items(); 2) iterating each record & changing their column values by using, record.set() 3) now, the records are dirt: true but I have to use some metod to out them in store & then use sync method

Comment: What version of ExtJS? The data layer saw some pretty large changes between v3 and v4.

Comment: Sry I hv changed the tag, its sencha touch 1.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sencha Touch 1.1.1 has a bug that can cause updated records to not be saved. I've worked around the issue by manually setting the isDirty flag on the record to true, and then calling store.sync()

So:

```
var index = store.find('name','Hello World');
var record = store.getAt(index);
record.set('value', 'new value' );
record.dirty = true;
store.sync();
```

I'm using the offlinestore proxy.

See Also:
http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?153432-1.1.1-broke-store.sync-for-modified-records/